# Dealing with functions in a class that should be broken down into functions for clarity?

Tags: c++, oop

How is this situation usually dealt with. For example, an object may need to do very specific things:

```
class Human
{
   public:
   void eat(Food food);
   void drink(Liquid liquid);
   String talkTo(Human human);
}
```

Say that this is what this class is supposed to do, but to actually do these might result in functions that are well over 10,000 lines. So you would break them down. The problem is, many of those helper functions should not be called by anything other than the function they are serving. This makes the code confusing in a way. For example, chew(Food food); would be called by eat() but should not be called by a user of the class and probably should not be called anywhere else.

How are these cases dealt with generally. I was looking at some classes from a real video game that looked like this:

```
class CHeli (7 variables, 19 functions)
Variables list

    CatalinaHasBeenShotDown
    CatalinaHeliOn
    NumScriptHelis
    NumRandomHelis
    TestForNewRandomHelisTimer
    ScriptHeliOn
    pHelis

Functions list

    FindPointerToCatalinasHeli (void)
    GenerateHeli (b)
    CatalinaTakeOff (void)
    ActivateHeli (b)
    MakeCatalinaHeliFlyAway (void)
    HasCatalinaBeenShotDown (void)
    InitHelis (void)
    UpdateHelis (void)
    TestRocketCollision (P7CVector)
    TestBulletCollision (P7CVectorP7CVectorP7CVector)
    SpecialHeliPreRender (void)
    SpawnFlyingComponent (i)
    StartCatalinaFlyBy (void)
    RemoveCatalinaHeli (void)
    Render (void)
    SetModelIndex (Ui)
    PreRenderAlways (void)
    ProcessControl (void)
    PreRender (void)
```

All of these look like fairly high level functions, which mean their source code must be pretty lengthy. What is good about this is that at a glance it is very clear what this class can do and the class looks easy to use. However, the code for these functions might be quite large.

What should a programmer do in these cases; what is proper practice for these types of situations.

Comment: I usually use private methods, or if possible static free functions in the appropriate .cpp file, with a comment saying "This is a subroutine of <entrypoint>", and trust people not to call them inappropriately, but I am curious to hear better ideas.

Comment: Catalina? Heli? This isn't from GTA3, is it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> For example, chew(Food food); would be called by eat() but should not be called by a user of the class and probably should not be called anywhere else.

Then either make `chew` a `private` or `protected` member function, or a freestanding function in an anonymous namespace inside the `eat` implementation module:

```
// eat.cc

// details of digestion
namespace {
    void chew(Human &subject, Food &food)
    {
        while (!food.mushy())
            subject.move_jaws();
    }
}

void Human::eat(Food &food)
{
    chew(*this, food);
    swallow(*this, food);
}
```

The benefits of this approach compared to `private` member functions is that the implementation of `eat` can be changed without the header changing (requiring recompilation of client code). The drawback is that the function cannot be called by any function outside of its module, so it can't be shared by multiple member functions unless they share an implementation file, and that it can't access `private` parts of the class directly.

The drawback compared to `protected` member functions is that derived classes can't call `chew` directly.

Comment: Interesting, I always thought this was more of a C / procedural approach (thus the passing of this) and therefore a bad idea in OOP.

Comment: @Milo: C++ is not a pure OOP language and features freestanding functions, for good reasons. Many problems call for a non-OO solution.

Comment: @Milo OOP is not about moving free functions into classes! Although in this case I don't see any problem with a private method instead of a free function.

Comment: @ChristianRau: the problem with `private` functions in C++ is that they have to be publicly declared, in the header. C++ `private` functions leak implementation details and trigger recompilation when the implementation changes.

Comment: @larsmans Ok, that's true. But I still don't consider them evil, especially if they need access to other private members of the object (yes I know, they should rather use the public interface, but well ...).

Comment: @Cristian: If there are not already too many arguments, I'd rather have the caller pass a reference to the private member in question.

Comment: @ChristianRau: `private` members are necessary sometimes, but I prefer local functions and use them whenever possible.

Comment: It's actually better encapsulation to put implementation detail functions into a namespace in the .cpp for the reasons already mentioned here. You can have it be anonymous like this example or you can do like the boost library and have a `namespace detail` for your helper functions which shouldn't be members and shouldn't be used elsewhere.

Comment: @AJG85: agree, with the remark that a `detail` namespace is most useful in template libraries and anonymous namespaces should be preferred elsewhere.

Comment: @larsmans Yup namespaces can get out of control easily especially once you start preferring free functions to members where possible. If a name is used it should be clear what belongs there.

Comment: @larsmans: there is actually an objective criteria to choose between `private` method and free-function --> sometimes the public API is not sufficient to perform the task in a free function, in which case you just have to use a `private` method (note: making the free function a friend would not achieve anything...) ... and one solution to avoid this is the use of the PIMPL idiom, where `private` (implementation) methods become unnecessary (you might still want to provide `private virtual` methods for "hooks").

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I had come to more or less the same conclusion and have updated the answer in a similar vein.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of one member function is allowed to be split in whatever way you want.

A popular option is to use private member functions:

```
struct Human
{
    void eat();

private:
    void chew(...);
    void eat_spinach();
    ...
};
```

or to use the Pimpl idiom:

```
struct Human
{
    void eat();
private:
    struct impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> p_impl;
};

struct Human::impl { ... };
```

However, as soon as the complexity of `eat` goes up, you surely don't want a collection of private methods accumulating (be it inside a Pimpl class or inside a private section).

So you want to break down the behavior. You can use classes:

```
struct SpinachEater
{
    void eat_spinach();
private:
    // Helpers for eating spinach
};

...

void Human::eat(Aliment* e)
{
    if (e->isSpinach()) // Use your favorite dispatch method here
                        // Factories, or some sort of polymorphism
                        // are possible ideas.
    {
        SpinachEater eater;
        eater.eat_spinach();
    }

    ...
}
```

with the basic principles:

- Keep it simple
- One class one responsibility
- Never duplicate code

Edit: A slightly better illustration, showing a possible split into classes:

```
struct Aliment;

struct Human
{
    void eat(Aliment* e);

private:
    void process(Aliment* e); 
    void chew();
    void swallow();
    void throw_up();
};

// Everything below is in an implementation file
// As the code grows, it can of course be split into several
// implementation files.
struct AlimentProcessor
{
    virtual ~AlimentProcessor() {}
    virtual process() {}
};

struct VegetableProcessor : AlimentProcessor
{
private:
    virtual process() { std::cout << "Eeek\n"; }
};

struct MeatProcessor
{
private:
    virtual process() { std::cout << "Hmmm\n"; }
};

// Use your favorite dispatch method here.
// There are many ways to escape the use of dynamic_cast,
// especially if the number of aliments is expected to grow.
std::unique_ptr<AlimentProcessor> Factory(Aliment* e)
{
    typedef std::unique_ptr<AlimentProcessor> Handle;

    if (dynamic_cast<Vegetable*>(e)) 
        return Handle(new VegetableProcessor);
    else if (dynamic_cast<Meat*>(e))
        return Handle(new MeatProcessor); 
    else
        return Handle(new AlimentProcessor);
};

void Human::eat(Aliment* e)
{
    this->process(e);
    this->chew();

    if (e->isGood()) this->swallow();
    else this->throw_up();
}

void Human::process(Aliment* e)
{
    Factory(e)->process();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to (perhaps `private`ly) compose the `Human` of smaller objects that each do a smaller part of the work. So, you might have a `Stomach` object. `Human::eat(Food food)` would delegate to `this->stomach.digest(food)`, returning a `DigestedFood` object, which the `Human::eat(Food food)` function processed further.

Answer (score 0):

Function decomposition is something that is learnt from experience, and it usually implies type decomposition at the same time. If your functions become too large there are different things that can be done, which is best for a particular case depends on the problem at hand.

- separate functionality into private functions

This makes more sense when the functions have to access quite a bit of state from the object, and if they can be used as building blocks for one or more of the public functions

- decompose the class into different subclasses that have different responsibilities

In some cases a part of the work falls naturally into its own little subproblem, then the higher level functions can be implemented in terms of calls to the internal subobjects (usually members of the type).

Because the domain that you are trying to model can be interpreted in quite a number of different ways I fear trying to provide a sensible breakdown, but you could imagine that you had a `mouth` subobject in `Human` that you could use to `ingest` food or drink. Inside the `mouth` subobject you could have functions `open`, `chew`, `swallow`...